# invoke slim instead of erb in rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have been trying to use default template engine as slim. But what ever the way i try i get erb instead of slim.
I used

```
gem 'slim-rails'
```

as suggested but that didnt work. I have added this piece of code in my application.rb as suggested

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine :slim
end
```

this didnt work.
I have been trying to configure devise views with this command

```
rails g devise:views
```

This always invokes erb. How to invoke slim template engine instead of erb.

Comment: It seems as though devise doesn't support slim out of the box. Try this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-Haml-and-Slim-Views

Comment: Hi [DickieBoy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1141264/dickieboy) the method mentioned in the wiki worked perfectly